# Is permit required in Rohtang Pass when coming from Keylong to Manali with your own motorbike?

Tags: india, driving, motorcycles, north-india

We are travelling from Leh to Manali by motorbike, so we will be crossing the Rohtang pass on AUG 7, 2015 Friday. Please let us know do we need any permit or should we wait in the pass. I heard a permit is required to cross from Manali to Keylong. But not sure about Keylong to Manali. Please help

Comment: Bike means motorbike or bicycle? Does it make a difference?

Comment: @JoErNanO : Motorbike

Comment: +1...This is very confusing. It seems like the rules change every week and nobody knows what they are today.

Answer (score 1):

You only [need a permit when you go from Manali to Keylong](http://www.indiatravelforum.in/threads/manali-leh-highway-travel-guide.618/) but on the way back there is no permit required. I would still advise asking when you are at Manali because rules do keep changing a lot and the government is not very proactive in letting people know about the changes.